# Does the Outlook.context.roamingSettings API work in Outlook preview (Monarch)?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

Does the Outlook.context.roamingSettings API work in Outlook preview (Monarch)?

Version information: 1.2023.727.100

[image: outlook version info]

The API request seems to be translated to the following URL which attempts to update the configuration, but this fails with a 500 internal server error.

[image: internal server error]